# Scrape span tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have problem to scrape this code.
[image]

This is my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need regex selector, just select the nearest class then use `.next_sibling`

```
ranks = soup.select('.item_color_title')
for rank in ranks:
    rank = rank.next_sibling
    # cleanup non alphanumeric: "     520th (" ==> 520th
    rank = re.sub(r'\W', '', rank)
    print(rank)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aleksandre Tsertsvadze, please do not post pictures of code, but the code itself inside code blocks. Also, try to provide minimal reproducible example, what's gone wrong, or what you actually expect the code to do.

**I could NOT reproduce the issue.** I tried to mimic your code style, and here's what I got -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<span class="class_1 class_2"> mathing </span> <span> empty </span>
 "                   ()blabla "  <span class="class_1"> mathing2 </span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all("span", class_=re.compile("^class_1")):
  print(item)
```

**Output on python 3.8 -**

```
<span class="class_1 class_2"> mathing </span>
<span class="class_1"> mathing2 </span>
```

What issue are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import re
for tag in soup_obj.find_all(re.compile("^span")):
    print(tag.next) # text
    print(tag) # tag
```